# How to calculate modulo with power?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How is the approach of solving a modular equation like this

$75^5 \equiv x \pmod {91}$ ?

I was first thinking of Fermat's Little Theorem but I couldn't get anywhere with it. I guess it because 91 is larger than 5?

Do I have to use a modular exponentiation? How do I do this?

Comment: Use the fact that $91=7\times13$ to decompose the congruence into a simpler system of congruences.

Answer (score 1):

$$75\operatorname{mod} 91\equiv -16\operatorname{mod}{91}\to75^5\operatorname{mod}91\equiv-2^{20}\operatorname{mod}91$$
There is decomposition $91=7^113^1$, which means that we can consider congruences:
$$
\begin{cases}
x\equiv-2^{20}\operatorname{mod}7\\
x\equiv-2^{20}\operatorname{mod}13
\end{cases}
$$
Due to the Fermat's Little Theorem $2^{6}\operatorname{mod}7\equiv1$ and $2^{12}\operatorname{mod}13\equiv1$
$$
\begin{cases}
x\equiv-2^{20}\operatorname{mod}7=-2^2\operatorname{mod}7=-4\operatorname{mod}7=3\operatorname{mod}7\\
x\equiv-2^{20}\operatorname{mod}13=-2^{8}\operatorname{mod}13=-16^2\operatorname{mod}13=-9\operatorname{mod}13=4\operatorname{mod}13
\end{cases}
$$
Thus, we have system:
$$
\begin{cases}
x\equiv3\operatorname{mod}7\\
x\equiv4\operatorname{mod}13
\end{cases}
$$
From first equation it follows that solution should be in form $x=3+7m$, where $m$ is integer. It easy to see that smallest positive value of $m$ which satisfies second eqution is $2$, hence $x=17$.
$$
75^5\operatorname{mod} 91 = 17\operatorname{mod} 91
$$

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas that I think you'll be able to generalize:
$$\begin{cases}3^3=1\pmod{13}\\{}\\3^3=-1\pmod7\implies 3^6=1\pmod7\end{cases}\;\;\implies 3^6=1\pmod{7\cdot13=91}$$

and now

$$\begin{cases}25=-1\pmod{13}\implies 25^2=1\pmod{13}\\{}\\25=-3\pmod7\implies 25^6=1\pmod7\end{cases}\;\;\implies 25^6=1\pmod{91}$$

Thus, we get that

$$75^3=3^325^3=1\cdot(-1)\pmod{91}\implies\ldots$$